# How to using more APIs in the app in android

Tags: android

Is there any way to using more APIs in App and Switching between them is done by a radio button?
I want to use google books, Amazon, ... and when the user click search book the  app will download result on the screen.
I've used google book Api but how to use more APIs to show more results.

Comment: Yes of course you can. What library are you using for API calls?

Comment: i used parse response json through constants directly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use many API as you want, you can use retrofit 2, and with that create the differents @GET and just call it when you need it o/

Comment: thanks any links to explain how to use that? i'm new developer